# How to get HTML code of selected text in ckeditor 5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

How to get HTML of the selected text in ckeditor 5?

In ckeditor 4 there is getHTML() method. What is the analog in the 5th version?

Comment: The [`getData()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html#function-getData) method should work. _"By default the editor outputs HTML."_

Comment: There is no such method in Selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DataController#stringify](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_controller_datacontroller-DataController.html#function-stringify) and [getSelectedContent](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_utils_getselectedcontent.html) as Alexandros Kyriakos suggested, it can also be done like this:

```js
let sHtmlSelection = this.editor.data.stringify(this.editor.model.getSelectedContent(this.editor.model.document.selection));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataController#stringify](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_controller_datacontroller-DataController.html#function-stringify) to stringify your HTML from document's fragment using the [getSelectedContent](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_utils_getselectedcontent.html)

```
import getSelectedContent from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/utils/getselectedcontent";

export default class CK5Utils{
        static getSelectedHtml(ed) {
            const {model, data, model:{document:{selection}}} = ed;
            const range = selection.getFirstRange();
            if (range.end.isEqual(range.start)) {
              return '';
            }
            const selected = getSelectedContent(model, selection);
            return data.stringify(selected);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the selected text within a range, but to get the HTML, it is a bit more tricky.

I was able to grab the `name` of the `parent` and run the value through a `switch` statement.

**Note:** The code below has been adapted from here: *["Get the highlighted/selected text in CKEDITOR 5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196777)*

```js
const resultArea = document.querySelector('.selected');

let globalEditor;

ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
  .then(editor => globalEditor = editor)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

const formatNode = (node) => {
  switch (node.parent.name) {
    case 'heading1'  : return `<h1>${node.data}</h1>`;
    case 'heading2'  : return `<h2>${node.data}</h2>`;
    case 'heading3'  : return `<h3>${node.data}</h3>`;
    case 'paragraph' : return `<p>${node.data}</p>`;
    default          : return '';
  }
};

const getSelectedHTML = (editor) =>
  [...editor.model.document.selection.getFirstRange().getItems()]
    .filter(node => node.data)
    .map(formatNode)
    .join('\n');

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  resultArea.value = getSelectedHTML(globalEditor);
});
```

```html
<!-- https://cdn.ckeditor.com/#ckeditor5 -->
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/23.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is some sample content.</p>
</div>
<p>
  <button class="btn">Get Selected HTML</button>
</p>
<textarea class="selected" rows="8" cols="72"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is a very hard way to do the job well. Though I cannot find anything better.